# Torque qsub -o command not work

Tags: torque

I made a test script `test.qsub`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#PBS -q batch 
#PBS -o output.txt 
#PBS -e Error.err 
echo "hello world"
```

When running `qsub test.qsub`  it does not generate the `output.txt` file nor the file `error.txt`.  I also believe that the other options do not work either, appreciate your help ! It is said you should configure the `torque.cfg` but in my installation the file is not generated and not in `/var/spool/torque`.

Comment: Do you learn anything from looking at the tracejob output? My guess is that ssh keys aren't configured to scp the file from the compute node to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Try "#PBS -k oe". This directs pbs to keep stdout and stderr.